# How to find the source of $PATH?

Tags: path, centos7, bash

I'm using a Centos 7 server. I'm entering the command `echo $PATH` and trying to figure out where it's getting the path that it's putting out. The path doesn't match what's in my .bash_profile, and there is no .bashrc file. How do I find out where my current $PATH is being sourced from?

Answer (score 0):

The Default values for .bashrc and $PATH are stored in files `/etc/bashrc` and `/etc/profile`. These files are used by shell and kernel for setting default values for proper functioning of the server.

I would advise not to change any values here, as it might cause abnormal behavior in the server.